# Matlab serial communication inconsistency

Tags: matlab

I want to control a Prior ProScan II controller and the fitting motorized stage with Matlab R2016b. [Manual](http://www.prior-us.com/files/Proscan-II-Operating-Manual.pdf) Tested with R2010b, got the same results.  The relevant commands of the stage are VS(page 46), P(p.43), PS(p.44). In a plain terminal, immediately after the stage halts I can issue the P or PS command, returning the current position of the X and Y axes. If done in Matlab prompt, it MIGHT need a second or two to return the proper value, before that it returns 'R' - Probably not the ACK of the previous command as it is returned after init, without any R-ACKed commands issued before. When used in a script in a separate .m file, it can only return 'R'. My code in main.m is as follows:

```
%Opening serial port
s = serial('COM9');
set(s,'BaudRate',9600,'Terminator','CR');  %Note that CR will be concatenated to all commands
fopen(s);
s       %print for debugging

t=1     %loop index

while true
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %Here is code to mess with a joystick that works fine, using VS command
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    if button(joy, 3) == 1          %Button3 of joystick should trigger position reading
        fprintf(s,'vs,0,0');        %Halt joystick movement 
        pause(1)                    %Debouncing
        fprintf(s,'p');             %Axe-pos reading command
        fgets(s)                    %Reading the answer
end


%This way to increment follows the skipped parts and is required for timing
if mod(t, 100)==0
        fprintf(s,'%s',Command);
        t=1;
    else
        t=t+1;
end
```

If the segment in if..end is invoked from the Matlab prompt, it works fine in most cases.

```
>> s = openserial()
%properties as before, skipped to save space
>> fprintf(s,'ps');
>> fgets(s)

ans =

100000,100000
```

or

```
>> fprintf(s,'p');
>> fgets(s)

ans =

100000,100000,0
```

If I Ctrl+C out of the infinite loop but leave the serial open and issue

```
>> fprintf(s,'p');
>> fgets(s)

ans = 

R
```

returns. Using fscanf() instead of fgets() yields the same results.

Is there any known bug of fprintf() or the ones mentioned above that could cause this? What could I do to succesfully and consistently read within a script? Thank you for any answers.

Comment: Solution was to force flush the serial input buffer, flushinput(s) before pause(1). I still don't know why it worked fine outside the script and not within.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to force flush the serial input buffer, flushinput(s) before the line pause(1). For some reason, even fscanf() instead of fgets() didn't flush it. I still don't know why it worked fine outside the script but not within. Additionally, it also worked in a separate script.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar problem of timeout as given here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667884/timeout-on-waiting-for-command-from-serial-communication-device-using-matlab. Did you ever face such a problem ?